# Upload image on AWS server and take backup

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I created a spring boot application when users uploads images I just create the folder at the project level and add an image to it using Rest API.

At the local host create the folder and the image save successfully.

Now it's time to deploy on the AWS server. But when I need a backup of the project-level image folder. is it possible? and How?

Comment: quick questions :- 
1) Where have you uploaded your application  on ec2 ( going by the ec2 tag)?
2) What is the meaning of project-level image?

Comment: Application runs on Elastic Beanstalk, and I created folder at "project.images" using rest API if the folder is not found

Comment: If its beanstalk, it is probably storing project related data inside ebs volume, since i dont know the details, in my view you cannot just backup project level images if its in ebs volume, you need to make a copy of ebs volume which will copy entire project related data.
If you want to exclusively copy images folder, you need to change your code and store it in s3 bucketm, which gives you more flexibility to copy images only.

does this help?